# AngularJS directive replacing itself won't replace back

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which I want to conditionally wrap it's contents, to enable this usage:

text becomes link of outer a is present

I'm trying to do that with this link function:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs['conditionalWrap'], (value) => {
              if (!value) {
                  element.replaceWith(element.contents());
              }
          });
      }
```

This does work, but only in 1 direction. So if the directive is rendered with outer  enabled and the watched expression changes, it removes the outer . But if a watched expression changes again it won't add the outer tag back. The code is getting executed (debugger steps into it) but it just doesn't work. Also the element paramater is always the instance of the template, so it always contains the outer  tag.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
What I found out is that somehow I'm losing the inner contents. Lets say I have this:

```
<a href conditional-wrap="expression">
    SOMETHING INSIDE!!!
</a>
```

When I get into the scope.$watch as above, as long as expression is(and was) true, element parameter is this whole snippet. Once I've set the expression to false and the scope.$watch ran and replaces the element, subsequent runs (when expression changes) get this as element parameter:

```
<a href conditional-wrap="expression"></a>
```

Inner contents is missing, *but* the html rendered by this directive is still the inner contents.

UPDATE2: here's a very simple example demonstrating the loss of inner HTMl in the element, but actually rendering it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/oxp5zxag/

UPDATE3: this is rather a problem with _.replaceWith() function, it doesn't seem to do what is intuitive, lets see if I figure this out

Comment: did you tried to $digest after replace ?

Comment: the code inside scope.$watch is executed in a digest, so calling digest would lead to "digest already in progress"

Comment: Could you reproduce the behaviour in a Fiddle or Plunkr please?

Comment: I'll do. I found out I'm losing the inner contents somehow, post updated

Comment: replaceWith() is doing what it is told to, whenever it runs. somehow you should save outer HTML